# UK Dividends template

Tags: united-kingdom, dividends

I'm running a very small limited company in the UK and I just found out that I need to produce dividends vouchers and minute meetings even if I'm the only shareholder.

The problem I have is with the following sentence

*An interim dividend of £2,500 per £1 ordinary share for the year ended [year-ended date] to be paid to the shareholder registered at the close of business on 13/03/2020.*

Should [year-ended-date] be 05/04/2020 because the current UK tax year ends on 05/04/2020? Or should it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the company year end, i.e. the end date of your limited company reporting period.

This is often 31 March, or perhaps it's 30 June, 31 September, 31 December if you've decided to shift it by a quarter or two or three.

Comment: if I formed the company on October 24, 2019 should it be October 23, 2020?

Comment: That would be unusual! Report to the end of a month or quarter is usual. Stick to 31 March. It doesn't have to be a full year of trading.